# Does the jTds 1.3.1 driver work with both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7?

Tags: driver, java, jtds

Does the jTds 1.3.1 driver work with both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7?
Or do I need to use jTds 1.2.7 for JDK 1.6 and jTds 1.3.1 for JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.3.1 does not guarantee backwards compatibility. From my experience there are certain JTDS incompatibility issues on specific versions of windows.

> https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/news/2012/10/jtds-jdbc-driver-127-and-130-released/

Answer (score 1):

To use jtds with JDK 6 latest version we can use is jtds 1.2.7.

Detailed discussion about why you can't use 1.3.1 with JDK 6 and other things can be found at

http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/104388/thread/f436f063/

Answer (score 0):

jtds 1.2.8 is possible to use with java 1.6. While jtds 1.3.0 is using java 1.7